# How is R handling numbers so that they are the same but not indentical() after exporting and re-importing?

Tags: r, import, dataframe, export, number-formatting

A and B should be the same dataframe.  A is generated in R, B is A exported and them imported back into R.

Both have dimensions 49 x 97, with the first column characters and all other columns numbers.
`str()` lists them as "chr" and "num" respectively.

Depending on how I look at the number columns, sometimes R finds them identical and sometimes not:

```
> identical(A,B)

FALSE
#The dataframes A and B are not the same

> identical(A[,1],B[,1])

TRUE
#The character-containing columns are the same

> identical(A[,-1],B[,-1])

FALSE
#The number-containing columns are not the same

> identical(matrix(A[,-1]),matrix(B[,-1]))

TRUE
#If the number-containing columns are converted into a matrix, they are the same

> identical(as.matrix(A[,-1]),as.matrix(B[,-1]))

FALSE
> identical(as.matrix(A[1:49,-1]),as.matrix(B[1:49,-1]))

TRUE
#But if they're converted into a matrix using as.matrix() instead of
# matrix() they're only the same if the 49 rows are explicitly indexed
```

My question:
What is the difference in how R interprets the numbers?
Are they sometimes treated as doubles and sometimes as floating points?
How do you know when R will do one or the other, and can I be sure that A and B really are the same?

---

**EDIT: my advice after another 2 yrs experience in R:**

- use `all.equal()` instead of `identical()` to see an explanation of what's different and to ignore minute rounding errors
- use `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` to export and re-import with exact same format (and much faster)
- remember that `matrix()` and `as.matrix()` can behave differently

Comment: By export them import, do you mean `read.table` and then `write.table` (or one of their variants)?.  If so, they can differ because text and binary values may differ, but typically not by more than 10^-16.   You can test this by checking `max(abs(A-B))`.   If you want identical values between sessions, use `readRDS` and `saveRDS`.

Comment: It may be difficult to answer this without providing us a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the help page for `identical`. It applies a much more stringent and extensive set of tests than just checking whether numerical entries are the same. All of the attributes of R objects including names and non-printing attributes are checked for identity. if you want to check numerical equivalent then perhaps you should first be stripping the objects of attributes, perhaps with `as.vector` or similar functions.